# How save scroll position and add to state in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have MainWrapper where api request, returns object with items(20pcs). Data api response i transfer to component(main page in routing). In MainWrapper have two routs: main page and detail page.

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={(props) => (
      <PokemonCardContainer
        pokemons={pokemons}
        search={search}
        loading={loading}
        error={error}
        lastPokemonElementRef={lastPokemonElementRef}
        handleSearch={handleSearch}
      />
    )}
  />
  <Route exact path="/pokemon/:pokemonName" component={Pokemon} />
</Switch>
```

In main page i construct list with items. When I reach the end of the list, api request updated and add new 20psc items in list and etc. Also next to each item there is button leads to detail page this item. **I want save scroll position when go to detail page and when I come back the position was on the element by which I clicked**.
In component which is main page i create new state:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState([0, 0]);
```

Next I made a click handler where I can find out the coordinates of the scroll:

```
const getCurrentScrollPosition = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let cordsAfterClick = [];
    let cords = ["scrollX", "scrollY"];
    cords.forEach((cord) => {
      cordsAfterClick.push(window[cord]);
    });
    console.log("Array with cords: ", cordsAfterClick);
    setScrollPosition(cordsAfterClick);
    console.log("State scrollPosition after update state: ", scrollPosition);
  };
```

[image]

ps: and i see `setScrollPosition` does not update state...
`e.preventDefault()` - only for test.
And i use:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition[0], scrollPosition[1]);
  }, [scrollPosition]);
```

**UPD:** Code updated. The comments below helped to understand the problem.
State:

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState({
    scrollX: 0,
    scrollY: 0,
  });
```

Click handler:

```
const getCurrentScrollPosition = (e) => {
    let cordsAfterClick = {};
    let cords = ["scrollX", "scrollY"];
    cords.forEach((cord) => {
      cordsAfterClick[cord] = window[cord];
    });
    localStorage.setItem("scrollCord", JSON.stringify(cordsAfterClick));
  };
```

useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setScrollPosition((prevScrollCord) => {
      return {
        ...prevScrollCord,
        ...JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("scrollCord")),
      };
    });
    window.scrollTo(scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY);
  }, [scrollPosition.scrollX, scrollPosition.scrollY]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to listen for the scroll event inside a useEffect like this:

```
useEffetch(() => {
  const handleScroll = e => {
   // set scroll values in state
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  // Remove listener when component unmounts
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks for comment! so I want to know the position at the time of the сlick. How to pass handleScroll to component in onClick?

Comment: You don't need to do that, the scroll position is already stored in the state before the click since user has scrolled to that item. You don't have to worry about the click, the scroll position will always be in the state.

Comment: thanks. But where do I get the necessary values to update the state?

Comment: inside handleScroll you can access `window.scrollY`

Comment: Sure!!! but so far I can’t do it :( the state is updated, but after returning the page is still at the beginning...

Comment: Oh I think you need to store the scroll position in the localStorage as well because when you change the route the component is unmounted and the state is gone. So you need to store it to localStorage and then access it from there.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox so I can help you better?

Comment: the coordinates are stored in the state after returning and the component not unmounted. i think may be need to use window.scroll('coord from state') but and this not work )

Comment: Well without any code to work on I don't think I can help you much, I'm sorry man

Comment: Yes you are right. the component is unmounted. and I had to use local storage. but noticed, if I do not use settimeout, the component does not have time to render and the scroll has the wrong position.  https://codesandbox.io/s/pokemons-sxbld my code

Comment: You'll have to show me the code, or else I'm of no use :(

Comment: codesand: https://codesandbox.io/s/pokemons-sxbld . containers/PokemonCardContainer/ -> here i set the scroll and use timeout

Comment: Hey it's working fine for me. I just tried it. When I click the button and go to details page and then click the back button, I'm standing where I left off.

Comment: works because i use settimeout. but I think this is not very good. try again please, I turned off the settimeout

Comment: I think I know the reason why it's working fine when you put a `setTimeout`, it's because if you don't put it then scroll is set before all the pokemons are fetched and images are loaded. Then when data comes in and images are loaded the scroll of the page changes to accomodate the UI changes. I hope it gives you a direction. To prove my point I would ask you to give `PokemonCard` a fixed height and you'll see a big difference, I'm still not sure how to handle images load

Comment: you're right! thank you for the explanation !! if I set a fixed PokemonCard height, everything works correctly!
I will edit my question, supplement it with your solutions and note your answer that it helped me! :)